# Binding to transient properties in a collection view in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to understand the best way to bind properties in a collection of views.

In an MVC architecture, according to your Docs, "we should actually be binding the properties of our views to the controller layer," not directly to model instances. This works great when we have a controller that is controlling just a single object, but it doesn't seem to work so well when we are dealing with collections.

In your cannonical ToDos example, your view is

```
{{#collection contentBinding="Todos.todosController" tagName="ul"
 itemClassBinding="content.isDone"}}
  {{view Em.Checkbox titleBinding="content.title"
    valueBinding="content.isDone"}}
{{/collection}}
```

This is essentially binding directly to each model's properties. I understand that the array controller is somehow proxying those properties, but you're still only able to refer to those properties that exist directly on the model objects.

Let's say in my ToDo's app I wanted to have a few more states on the view, for example, I want it to be able to be expanded or collapsed. If I have a view object that represents the entire ToDo view, including the expander frame and contents, I would want some property on that view, 'isExpanded', to be bound to something.

If I had just a single object and a non-array controller, I might put an 'isExpanded' property in the controller. Then when you flip the little triangle icon I could set this property on the controller, and the view would notice this and expand.

But with an array controller, there's no obvious way to have this property and have it refer to individual ToDos. From the cannonical example above, it seems that I would have to bind to a property on the model. But it seems silly to have to put it a transient, view-centered property like "isExpanded" right into the ToDo model iteself.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put a property on the controller. At least in Sproutcore, from which ember derives, this would cause the model status to change, which you don't want, since the property isn't on the model.  Furthermore, the expanded state of the view is a view concern; the model doesn't care about how its being displayed.  Stay MVC.

Put the `expanded` property on the view itself, and make it a value in the `displayProperties` array.  [Looking thru the ember code (line 599)](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js)

Whenever a value in that array changes, the view should rerender.  That's what I would do in Sproutcore, anyway.

Update for your comment.  Two approaches:

1) Define something like

```
displayProperties: ['expand']
...
expandBinding: Em.Binding.oneWay('xyz')
```

on your views.  That way, all of the item views will expand when your 1 trigger changes.

2) Keep references to your views, and in your statechart, when the user clicks the expand button, loop over the views and set the expand property.

Option 1 is simpler, but creating lots of bindings can affect performance.  Option 2 doesn't use lots of bindings.  Might want to start with option 1 and then if performance is a problem move to option 2.

Comment: But how would I made that view property change? Let's say a user clicks on a tag-name somewhere else in the app, and I want all of the ToDos with that associated tag to expand. What would I set in order to have the views of those ToDos expand? If isExpanded were a model property, I could just find all those models and set that property, and all of the associated views would be notified. But as we both said, that's a view concern and doesn't belong on the model.

Comment: Hmmm... still not understanding this. Option 1 doesn't distinguish between the views that I want to expand and the views that I don't want to expand. I don't want them all to expand, I just want ones (in my made-up example) where the user has clicked on a tag, and it seems that they should be bound to a property that can inform them of this. The issue isn't the displayProperties, I know how to re-render a view. The issue is what to I bind *to*? Saying 'xyz' doesn't answer that.

Comment: [SO saved my reply before I was ready, sorry.] Option 2 seems worse: it doesn't seem very MVC to have to maintain a separate array of all my models and views stored somewhere in the statechart (or elsewhere). I've never seen anyone do that in an Ember or SC app.

Comment: you don't, you just need to grab the views.  You don't need an array.  At least in SC, you can have an outlet on the page where your list is defined, and grab the views from there.  I don't think there is a completely clean solution.  If you put it on the model, you break MVC.  If you don't you have to do (slightly) more work.